# How to post request with spring boot web-client for Form data for content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

How To use spring boot `webclient` for posting request with  content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
sample curl request with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

```
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=XXXX' \
--data-urlencode 'password=XXXX'
```

How Can i send same request using webclient?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

We can use [`BodyInserters.fromFormData`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyInserters.html#fromFormData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) for this purpose

```
webClient client = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("SOME-BASE-URL")
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
        .build();

return client.post()
        .uri("SOME-URI)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", "SOME-USERNAME")
                .with("password", "SONE-PASSWORD"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(SomeClass.class)
                .onErrorMap(e -> new MyException("messahe",e))
        .blockLast();
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me. I get the following exception: `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters$DefaultFormInserter`

Comment: Nevermind. I used `bodyValue` instead of `body`. It works!

Answer (score 31):

In another form:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
formData.add("username", "XXXX");
formData.add("password", "XXXX");

String response = WebClient.create()
    .post()
    .uri("URL")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
    .exchange()
    .block()
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .block();
```

In my humble opinion, for simple request, [REST Assured](http://rest-assured.io/) is easier to use.

Comment: This will block the call, so it will wait until the request is finished and return

Comment: instead of ``.body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))`` should be ``.body(formData)``