# how to post body x-www-form-urlencoded using webclient?

Tags: java, spring, webclient

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> body_data = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
    body_data.add("param1", {param1});
    ...
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(api_url+request_url)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
            .build();

    String result = webClient.post().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                    .bodyValue(BodyInserters.fromFormData(body_data)).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

and it returns

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters$DefaultFormInserter; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters$DefaultFormInserter
```

Any suggestion for this?
content-type should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post request with spring boot web-client for Form data for content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792224/how-to-post-request-with-spring-boot-web-client-for-form-data-for-content-type-a)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use BodyInserters.fromFormData for this purpose:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("SOME-BASE-URL")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
            .build();
    
return client.post()
            .uri("SOME-URI)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", "SOME-USERNAME")
                    .with("password", "SONE-PASSWORD"))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(SomeClass.class)
                    .onErrorMap(e -> new MyException("messahe",e))
            .blockLast();
```

In another form:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
formData.add("username", "XXXX");
formData.add("password", "XXXX");

String response = WebClient.create()
    .post()
    .uri("URL")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
    .exchange()
    .block()
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .block();
```